# Commands work in Python (command line) but not in .py file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been trying to learn web scraping using Python. I followed instructions on some youtube videos. They started with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

This works in the Python command line (Python.exe), but not in my file. I suppose it works since it is not giving me an error. When I run the .py file I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Path\Web-Scrapy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

My first guess was that I didn't have the requests module installed, but when I ran `pip install requests` I received this:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\python34\lib\site-pac
kages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.6,>=2.5 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (
from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 in c:\python34\lib\site-pac
kages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python34\lib\site-packag
es (from requests)
```

Please help me, why am I getting this error?

Comment: probably because you're using 2 different versions of python.

Comment: how do you execute the file .py ?

Comment: I'm quite certain using Python 3.4, how do I confirm?

Comment: Run python3, not python, to make sure you're using requests from the right version of python. When you run pip, not pip3, it installs for Python2.

Comment: I press F5 in IDLE

Comment: Hmm, I think I got it

Comment: Oops, apparently I have 2 different versions of IDLE, 3.5.2 and 3.4. Version 3.5.2 gave me an error, 3.4 didn't! Thank you! :)